# "RENAME FIELDS Using xMap", on multiple fields

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I'm trying to use the "RENAME FIELDS using x;" function to rename fields in my tables, but i'm running into some strange behaviour and I was wondering if someone could explain why this is happening and how best to avoid it?

see my code below, you can see it will not rename column "BLAH", but why?

```
t_1:
mapping load * inline [
    Orig, New
    CUSTNO, CustomerNumber
    BLAH, CustomerNumber
];

test:
Load * inline [
    CUSTNO, Name
    1234, James

];

test2:
Load * inline [
    BLAH, Name2
    1235, Chris
];

RENAME FIELDS using t_1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how the `Rename Fields using X` is working.

The following is from QV Help:
`Two differently named fields cannot be renamed to having the same name. The script will run without errors, but the second field will not be renamed.`